# How to change group email lists in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Our work uses microsoft outlook. We have an attorneysandstaff@domain.com list, but some of those emails are no longer with us. How do I remove them? Is it as simple as going into the Microsoft 365 admin portal?

Comment: It greatly depends on what kind of object the group is, and where it's managed from in your organization. The most typical way to administratively manage an O365 distribution group would be to log into the exchange admin center > Recipients > Groups > Distribution lists > select the group > Members

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Cpt.Whale, what's the group your work uses?

If it's a [distribution group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/add-user-or-contact-to-distribution-list?view=o365-worldwide), as Cpt.Whale mentioned, just go to admin center and remove the members who are no longer with you.

If it's a contact group you created in Outlook, please double click to open the group, choose the members who are no longer with you and click Remove Member.
[image]

Hope the above help! If it is helpful, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.